# how to cd into previous directory

Tags: ubuntu, cd-command, alternatives

I am using Ubuntu and sometimes when I use `cd -` I don't go into the previous directory. And every time I get the directory which it `cd`ed to. example:-

```
$cd -
/home/[usrname]/Downloads
$cd -
/home/[usrname]/Downloads
```

is(/are) there and alternative(s)?

Comment: If you are using `bash`, do you have a `cd` command as part of `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, or in any command that sets the prompt (`$PS1`) or that executes automatically when you press `Enter`? Could you tell us what the shell outputs if you do `set -x` and then `cd` to some directory followed by `cd -`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could `cd $OLDPWD`. If `cd -` doesn't  work, check with `type -a cd` to see if `cd` had been overridden by a function or alias.

Comment: `type cd` works instead of `type -a cd`.

Comment: and it says `cd is a shell builtin`.

Comment: @user135142 Did you say that `type -a cd` "did not work"? What happened when you tried and what shell exactly are you using?

Comment: I know this answer has been accepted, but I fail to see that it actually resolves anything. It does not point to a solution and it does not explain any reasoning. The user says that `cd` is not an alias or function.

Comment: @they , this answer is what i need.

Comment: @user135142 Sure, it's just that it's not quite clear what the issue was and how the answer resolved it.  The answer just asks you to do some basic debugging, which you say you did and which points to `cd` _not being an alias or function_ (which the waltinator puts forward as a possible cause).  This means the cause was something else, but it's unclear what.

Comment: @they , the question was is there any alternatives to `cd -` because sometimes it doesn't work and always outputs the directory. this answer says `cd $OLDPWD` is an alternative. it worked for me so i accepted the answer.

Comment: @user135142 They are the same. In fact, when `cd` in the `bash` shell sees `-` as the argument, it substitutes the value of `$OLDPWD`.  You can see that in the source [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/cd.def#n349). If `cd -` does not work, then `cd $OLDPWD` would not work either (well, it may work if `$OLDPWD` is empty, meaning it takes you to the home directory, which means the next time you do the same `cd $OLDPWD` or `cd -`, it takes you to the directory you're already standing in, assuming you started in your home directory).